# Compilation failed for ejb

Tags: java, eclipse, ejb, weblogic-10.x, java-5

I'm struggling with this problem. It was working for me before, and suddenly when I did some changes in my interfaces and implementation class and when I try to build, I'm getting the following error. I tried uninstalling weblogic, jdk, everything. But still I have this problem. Please help me.. I'm using weblogic10.0 , jdk1.5.0_22, jre105.0_22, Eclipse indigo

```
Buildfile: C:\CeNAnalyticalPhase1\CeNStorageService\build.xml
clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\CeNAnalyticalPhase1\CeNStorageService\ant.build
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\CeNAnalyticalPhase1\CeNStorageService\dist
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\CeNAnalyticalPhase1\CeNStorageService\testreport
prepare:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\CeNAnalyticalPhase1\CeNStorageService\ant.build
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\CeNAnalyticalPhase1\CeNStorageService\ant.build\classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\CeNAnalyticalPhase1\CeNStorageService\ant.build\testclasses
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\CeNAnalyticalPhase1\CeNStorageService\dist
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\CeNAnalyticalPhase1\CeNStorageService\testreport
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\CeNAnalyticalPhase1\CeNStorageService\testreport\html
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\CeNAnalyticalPhase1\CeNStorageService\ant.build\classes\META-INF
     [copy] Copying 3 files to C:\CeNAnalyticalPhase1\CeNStorageService\ant.build\classes\META-INF
compile:
    [javac] C:\CeNAnalyticalPhase1\CeNStorageService\build.xml:194: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 179 source files to C:\CeNAnalyticalPhase1\CeNStorageService\ant.build\classes
    [javac] C:\CeNAnalyticalPhase1\CeNStorageService\src\com\pfizer\pgrd\chemistry\enotebook\storage\tests\TestCreateParallelNotebook.java:74: warning: [deprecation] createParallelExperiment(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) in com.pfizer.pgrd.chemistry.enotebook.storage.delegate.StorageDelegate has been deprecated
    [javac]               NotebookPageModel pageModel = storageObj.createParallelExperiment(spid, "27071975");
    [javac]                                                                   ^
    [javac] C:\CeNAnalyticalPhase1\CeNStorageService\src\com\pfizer\pgrd\chemistry\enotebook\storage\tests\TestCreateParallelNotebook.java:144: warning: [deprecation] createParallelExperiment(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) in com.pfizer.pgrd.chemistry.enotebook.storage.delegate.StorageDelegate has been deprecated
    [javac]       NotebookPageModel pageModel = storageObj.createParallelExperiment(spid, nbK );
    [javac]                                                   ^
    [javac] C:\CeNAnalyticalPhase1\CeNStorageService\src\com\pfizer\pgrd\chemistry\enotebook\storage\tests\TestNotebookInsertDAO.java:238: warning: [deprecation] putBytes(long,byte[]) in oracle.sql.BLOB has been deprecated
    [javac]             tempBlob.putBytes(1, bytes);
    [javac]                                 ^
    [javac] C:\CeNAnalyticalPhase1\CeNStorageService\src\com\pfizer\pgrd\chemistry\enotebook\storage\tests\loadtests\CreateExperimentTest.java:41: warning: [deprecation] createParallelExperiment(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) in com.pfizer.pgrd.chemistry.enotebook.storage.delegate.StorageDelegate has been deprecated
    [javac]                     NotebookPageModel page = ssi.createParallelExperiment(spid,notebook);
    [javac]                                                                     ^
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 4 warnings
compile-ejb:
   [wlappc] C:\CeNAnalyticalPhase1\CeNStorageService\ant.build\classes\com\pfizer\pgrd\chemistry\enotebook\storage\ejb\StorageRemote_ptetod_LocalHomeImpl.java:73: warning: non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;
   [wlappc] cast to java.lang.Class for a varargs call
   [wlappc] cast to java.lang.Class[] for a non-varargs call and to suppress this warning
   [wlappc]     "ejbCreate", null);
   [wlappc]                  ^
   [wlappc] C:\CeNAnalyticalPhase1\CeNStorageService\ant.build\classes\com\pfizer\pgrd\chemistry\enotebook\storage\ejb\StorageRemote_ptetod_LocalHomeImpl.java:77: warning: non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;
   [wlappc] cast to java.lang.Class for a varargs call
   [wlappc] cast to java.lang.Class[] for a non-varargs call and to suppress this warning
   [wlappc]         "ejbPostCreate", null); 
   [wlappc]                          ^
   [wlappc] C:\CeNAnalyticalPhase1\CeNStorageService\ant.build\classes\com\pfizer\pgrd\chemistry\enotebook\storage\ejb\StorageRemote_ptetod_Impl.java:11: com.pfizer.pgrd.chemistry.enotebook.storage.ejb.StorageRemote_ptetod_Impl is not abstract and does not override abstract method getSubmittedBatchAttachments(java.util.List) in com.pfizer.pgrd.chemistry.enotebook.storage.ejb.StorageRemote_ptetod_Intf
   [wlappc] public final class StorageRemote_ptetod_Impl
   [wlappc]              ^
   [wlappc] C:\CeNAnalyticalPhase1\CeNStorageService\ant.build\classes\com\pfizer\pgrd\chemistry\enotebook\storage\ejb\StorageRemote_ptetod_HomeImpl.java:132: warning: non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;
   [wlappc] cast to java.lang.Class for a varargs call
   [wlappc] cast to java.lang.Class[] for a non-varargs call and to suppress this warning
   [wlappc]     "ejbCreate", null);
   [wlappc]                  ^
   [wlappc] C:\CeNAnalyticalPhase1\CeNStorageService\ant.build\classes\com\pfizer\pgrd\chemistry\enotebook\storage\ejb\StorageRemote_ptetod_HomeImpl.java:136: warning: non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;
   [wlappc] cast to java.lang.Class for a varargs call
   [wlappc] cast to java.lang.Class[] for a non-varargs call and to suppress this warning
   [wlappc]         "ejbPostCreate", null); 
   [wlappc]                          ^
   [wlappc] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
   [wlappc] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
   [wlappc] 1 error
   [wlappc] 4 warnings

BUILD FAILED
C:\CeNAnalyticalPhase1\CeNStorageService\build.xml:214: weblogic.utils.compiler.ToolFailureException: [J2EE:160119]Appc is unable to process the file 'C:\CeNAnalyticalPhase1\CeNStorageService\ant.build\classes'. The following error occurred:

Compiler failed executable.exec

    at weblogic.ejb20.ejbc.EJBCompiler.doCompile(EJBCompiler.java:274)
    at weblogic.ejb20.ejbc.EJBCompiler.compileEJB(EJBCompiler.java:476)
    at weblogic.ejb20.ejbc.EJBCompiler.compileEJB(EJBCompiler.java:387)
    at weblogic.appc.compileEJB(appc.java:802)
    at weblogic.appc.compileEJB(appc.java:776)
    at weblogic.appc.compileInput(appc.java:463)
    at weblogic.appc.runBody(appc.java:184)
    at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:192)
    at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:147)
    at weblogic.appc.main(appc.java:1030)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at weblogic.ant.taskdefs.j2ee.CompilerTask.invokeMain(CompilerTask.java:278)
    at weblogic.ant.taskdefs.j2ee.Appc.privateExecute(Appc.java:200)
    at weblogic.ant.taskdefs.j2ee.Appc.execute(Appc.java:124)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:138)

java.io.IOException: Compiler failed executable.exec
    at weblogic.utils.compiler.CompilerInvoker.compileMaybeExit(CompilerInvoker.java:469)
    at weblogic.utils.compiler.CompilerInvoker.compile(CompilerInvoker.java:328)
    at weblogic.utils.compiler.CompilerInvoker.compile(CompilerInvoker.java:336)
    at weblogic.ejb20.ejbc.EJBCompiler.doCompile(EJBCompiler.java:270)
    at weblogic.ejb20.ejbc.EJBCompiler.compileEJB(EJBCompiler.java:476)
    at weblogic.ejb20.ejbc.EJBCompiler.compileEJB(EJBCompiler.java:387)
    at weblogic.appc.compileEJB(appc.java:802)
    at weblogic.appc.compileEJB(appc.java:776)
    at weblogic.appc.compileInput(appc.java:463)
    at weblogic.appc.runBody(appc.java:184)
    at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:192)
    at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:147)
    at weblogic.appc.main(appc.java:1030)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at weblogic.ant.taskdefs.j2ee.CompilerTask.invokeMain(CompilerTask.java:278)
    at weblogic.ant.taskdefs.j2ee.Appc.privateExecute(Appc.java:200)
    at weblogic.ant.taskdefs.j2ee.Appc.execute(Appc.java:124)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:138)

--------------- nested within: ------------------
weblogic.utils.compiler.ToolFailureException: [J2EE:160121]Errors encountered while compiling module 'C:\CeNAnalyticalPhase1\CeNStorageService\ant.build\classes':

Compiler failed executable.exec
 - with nested exception:
[
Compiler failed executable.exec
]
    at weblogic.appc.compileEJB(appc.java:781)
    at weblogic.appc.compileInput(appc.java:463)
    at weblogic.appc.runBody(appc.java:184)
    at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:192)
    at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:147)
    at weblogic.appc.main(appc.java:1030)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at weblogic.ant.taskdefs.j2ee.CompilerTask.invokeMain(CompilerTask.java:278)
    at weblogic.ant.taskdefs.j2ee.Appc.privateExecute(Appc.java:200)
    at weblogic.ant.taskdefs.j2ee.Appc.execute(Appc.java:124)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:138)
 - with nested exception:
[weblogic.utils.compiler.ToolFailureException: [J2EE:160121]Errors encountered while compiling module 'C:\CeNAnalyticalPhase1\CeNStorageService\ant.build\classes':

Compiler failed executable.exec
 - with nested exception:
[
Compiler failed executable.exec
]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your responses. I resolved the issue.Problem is we cannot use List as an argument in an ejb interface. It should be passed as an array instead. When I changed into array, build is success. This is the learning point for me.

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace is pretty clear: `StorageRemote_ptetod_Impl` doesn't override abstract method `getSubmittedBatchAttachments(java.util.List)` in `StorageRemote_ptetod_Intf`.

Comment: It's in ant.build classes file.. Created by jvm

Comment: There is no such file and I even deleted ant.build folder